# Angular unit test with different response from http response

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Hi everyone I am almost new in Angular and I want to create fail and success scenario for AUTH service code like below but somehow my success scenario unit test not pass.

```
    isAuthenticated(): Observable<any>{
    let token = String(localStorage.getItem('token'));
    return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiURL}/verify`,{ token: token }, {observe: 'response'})
      .pipe(
        map( (res:any) =>{
            if (res.body.user.imageURL) {
              res.user.imageURL = environment.hostURL + res.body.user.imageURL;
            }
            let user: User = res.body.user;
            this.userService.setCurrentUser(user)
            return of({ res: true , message: 'token is valid' })
        }),
        catchError(err=>{
          return of({ res: false , message: 'token is not valid' })
        })
      ) 
}
```

and here is my unit test

```
    it('should return success  result', (done: DoneFn) => {
    const mockSuccessResponse = { res: true, message: 'token is valid' };
    httpClientSpy.post.and.returnValue(asyncData(mockSuccessResponse));
      authService.isAuthenticated().subscribe({
      next: res => {
        expect(res)
          .withContext('expected login result')
          .toEqual(mockSuccessResponse);
        done();
      },
      error: done.fail
    });
    expect(httpClientSpy.post.calls.count())
      .withContext('one call')
      .toBe(1);  
});
```

the error I get is

[image: unit test does not pass]

I will appreciate for any help or suggestions

Answer (score 0):

The best way to acheive that is by using the `HttpClientTestModule` in your `TestBed` like this:

```
beforeEach(() => { 
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
      ],
      providers: []
    });
    httpMock = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
});
```

After that, you must use the `httpMock` to set the return value of the http call:

```
  httpMock
    .expectOne({ method: "POST", url: `${environment.apiURL}/verify` })
    .flush(mockSuccessResponse);
```

The best way to not have an error like

> An error was thrown in afterAll
> is to not use `done` but call it async like this:

```
it("should do something", async() => {
  // arrange
  const functionToTest = 
       lastValueFrom(authService.isAuthenticated());

      httpMock
        .expectOne({ method: "POST", url: `${environment.apiURL}/verify` })
        .flush(mockSuccessResponse);

  // act
  parametre = await functionToTest;
      
  // assert
  expect(parametre[0]).toEqual({ res: true , message: 'token is valid' });
});
```